# Divided by half - meaning

Tags: meaning

If someone says "Fifteen divided by half", I would interpret that literally to mean 15/0.5, or 30. However, I usually see it interpreted as 15/2, or 7.5.

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: If someone says *"Fifteen divided by half"*, it's probably either a slip of the tongue, or an understandable error by a non-native speaker. Most likely the intended expression would have been *"Fifteen divided* **in** *half"*.

Comment: Maybe depends on if this is about maths - because in maths you are right the answer is 30.

In normal English usage this is not a normal way to speak - which is probably why people find fractions so confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply grammatically incorrect, so it has no literal meaning. (And before anyone shows up to argue against prescriptivism, the very concept of a "literal meaning" contrary to what is meant/understood is prescriptivist at a basic level)

You could say "divided by *one* half", or "divided by 0.5" for one meaning; or "divided *in* half" for the other.

Comment: Random832 is right here. I would go further and insist that it's simply a typo/misspeech for "divided in half". For those who insist that it means "15 / 0.5", I would argue it means 15 divided by half of 15. The correct answer is 2. Any number divided by half is going to come out that way (except for zero, infinity, imaginary numbers, etc.)

Comment: Whether it is grammatically incorrect depends on the speaker, though I’ll grant that *by a half* and *by one-half* are probably significantly more common than *by half*. The idea that a prescriptively incorrect expression is ipso facto meaningless is not only absurd on its face but obviously false.

Comment: @JeffSahol: When 7.5 is intended, it probably is an error for *divided in half*, but the rest of your comment is, not to put too fine a point on it, nonsense. (And the mathematics is partly wrong as well: dividing an imaginary number other than zero by half of that number does indeed yield 2.)

Comment: I *knew* I was going to blow one of the math questions on this one! But I wanted it to sound nonsensical because that is how the 15/0.5 argument sounds to me: it does not help to interpret someone literally just to prove that they didn't express themselves correctly.

Comment: "is ipso facto meaningless" I didn't say that. I said that one cannot claim that a statement has a "literal meaning" contrary to what it _actually_ means (i.e. how the speaker means it and how it is generally understood to mean, _if_ it is generally understood at all) without adopting a prescriptivist viewpoint. I see "literal meaning", regarding anything other than intentional wordplay, as a synonym for "prescriptivist meaning".

Comment: @Random832: Yes, one can. *Divided by half* has a very clear literal meaning, which may or may not be the one intended by the speaker: it is synonymous with *divided by one-half*, which is misused and misunderstood in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Brian I beg to differ. `one half` or `a half` is a numerical quantity, but `half` is not, and cannot be used that way.

Comment: @Karl: You may differ until you’re blue in the face, but it won’t change the facts one iota: *half* used in that way is grammatical for some native speakers.

Comment: I would argue that no-one - native speaker or otherwise, _ever_ says "divided by half" meaning "multiplied by two". It either "literally means" divided in half, or it has no "literal meaning" at all. There's no basis - prescriptive or otherwise - for saying that it means multiplied by two.

Comment: The phrase may be meaningless/confusing/ambigous, but it is not clear why it would be regarded as 'grammatically incorrect'. Which rule of grammar is violated by it?

Comment: @jsw29 I suppose it's not grammatically incorrect, in the sense that English grammar by itself allows any noun here, but it has no more *mathematical* meaning than "divided by an orange". Perhaps 'grammatically' was the wrong word to use, but I don't know a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it's probably a grammatically incorrect attempt to say something was halved. It seems to be a somewhat common mistake if my peers in math classes are any indication. It seems to me to be a mix-up of "divided in half" and "reduced by half".

Answer (score 2):

You're right. *Fifteen divided by half* is 30, and that's that. Any other interpretation is incorrect. However, *fifteen by half* could be interpreted as *fifteen [multiplied] by half*, which would then give <sup>15</sup>/<sub>2</sub> or 7.5.

Comment: For completeness you might add that when 7.5 is intended, *15 divided by half* may be an error for *15 divided in half* (JeffSahol’s suggestion) or a conflation of *half of 15* with *15 divided by 2*. Of course this accounts only for errors in production; errors in interpretation are harder to understand.

Comment: "Half" is not a number, and that's that.

Comment: @Random832: Your assertion is contradicted by actual usage. People really do say and write things like *three-quarters is more than half*. You may, if you wish, deprecate the usage, just as I find your *how it is generally understood to mean* ungrammatical, but your assertion here is counterfactual rubbish.

Comment: "People really do say and write things like *three-quarters is more than half*." [citation needed]

Comment: More than half what? Half a cheeseburger? Half past ten?

Comment: @Karl: My own authority, for starters: having taught mathematics at an urban university for the last 36 years, I’ve a very good knowledge of the ways in which college students of all ages use numerical language. But with a simple web search you could have found [this](http://writtennerd.blogspot.com/2007/08/link-mad-response-american-reading.html) yourself.

Comment: That link doesn't support your argument - "half" in that is "half of americans", and is compared to another fraction phrase. There's no basis for "half" alone meaning "half [of one], the number/ratio itself".

Comment: I think the common usage would include an indefinite article -- _three-quarters is more than __a__ half_

Comment: Check any dictionary.  Half is not a number.  Period.  But admittedly many people use it as a number and end up adding confusion of this sort as a result.  If I write, "The soldiers emerged from the battle with their numbers divided by half."  You would assume if they went into the battle with 2000 men, there were 1000 men left.  You assumed I meant in half, because that fits the context.  If I say "2000 divided by half", you assume I mean one half because the context is I am telling you numbers.  Grammatically though half alone would mean half of the previous number referenced.

Comment: You can reasonably interpret "three quarters is more than half" as saying 3x/3 > 1x/2.  As if you are talking say pies you really mean 3/4 of a pie is more than half a pie.  In that you are treating three quarters as a modifier just like half.  You don't need half to be a number to make sense of this usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dividing numbers or objects into two equal parts, the expression to use is “divide in half,” not “divide by half.”

Technically, to divide a number by 1/2 is the same as to multiply it by 2.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please note that new answers should add something significant which is missing in the existing posts, rather than repeat what has already been stated.